# Import data from Source sheet to Destination sheet dynamically only by selecting the sheets in form of inputboxes not Mentioning their names in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I created a code in VBA to import all data from a source sheet to a destination sheet  dynamically ,without mentioning the names of sheets or maps in the vba code , only by selecting them in form of inputboxes.The names of cells in the first row  of  both sheets are the same  **But are  not in the same order**

```
 Dim wkbCrntWorkBook As Workbook
    Dim rngSourceRange As Range
    Dim rngDestination As Range
    Dim j As Long, lr1, lr2 As Long
    Dim r As Range
    Set wkbCrntWorkBook = ActiveWorkbook
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel 2007-13", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsa"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
            With Workbooks.Open(.SelectedItems(1)) ' open and reference current selected "source" workbook
                Set rngSourceRange = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select the range in the source sheet ", Title:="Source sheet chosing", Default:="A1", Type:=8) ' have user select any cell in source sheet
                  lr1 = rngSourceRange.Find("*", , xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
                 If Not rngSourceRange Is Nothing Then ' if any valid "source" range selected
                    wkbCrntWorkBook.Activate ' this allow user to switch between open workbooks
                    Set rngDestination = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select a destination cell", Title:="Select Destination", Default:="A1", Type:=8) ' have user select "destination" cell
                    
                   If Not rngDestination Is Nothing Then
               For j = 1 To rngSourceRange.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(1).Column
                  Set r = rngDestination.Rows(1).Find(rngSourceRange.Cells(1, j), , xlValues, xlWhole, , , False)
                 If Not r Is Nothing Then
                      'Importing data from origin sheet to Destination sheet'
                   rngDestination.Cells(1, r.Column).Resize(lr1).Value = rngSourceRange.Cells(2, j).Resize(lr1).Value
                    
           End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        
End If    
                    End If
                
                .Close False ' close referenced (i.e. current "source" sheet)
            End With
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

i can import the data from source sheet to destination sheet but the imported data landen in the wrong place because **the order of cells names of the first row is different from the source sheet **.
i tried to implement  the `j =1 To rngSourceRange.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(1).Column Set r = rngDestination.Rows(1).Find(rngSourceRange.Cells(1, j), , xlValues, xlWhole, , , False)`   to compare between the first rows of both sheets
and then import the data from source sheet  in the right place in the destination sheet.
but it is not working !!
i get a message of object fault  1004 infront of j=1 to..
how can i improve my code?

Comment: You need `End(xlToLeft)` or the correct value which is not 1.

Comment: i tried it  but nothing occurs !!

Comment: Perhaps it's not finding anything. check that by stepping through the code.

Answer (score 0):

Match source to destination columns using a [Dictionary Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/dictionary-object)

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub import()

    Dim wbSrc As Workbook
    Dim rngSrc As Range, rngDest As Range

    Dim dict As Object, key As String, arData, arHeader
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Dim sFile As String
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Excel 2007-13", "*.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsa"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show = -1 Then
           sFile = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With
    If sFile = "" Then Exit Sub
   
    Set wbSrc = Workbooks.Open(sFile, ReadOnly:=True)
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngSrc = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select the range in the source sheet ", _
                         Title:="Source sheet chosing", _
                         Default:="A1", Type:=8) ' have user select any cell in source sheet
    On Error GoTo 0
    If rngSrc Is Nothing Then
        wbSrc.Close
        Exit Sub
    ElseIf rngSrc.Rows.Count < 2 Then
        MsgBox "Source range must be 2 or more rows", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    Else
        ' copy source range to arrays
        arHeader = rngSrc.Rows(1).Value
        arData = rngSrc.Offset(1).Resize(rngSrc.Rows.Count - 1).Value
    End If

    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngDest = Application.InputBox(prompt:="Select a destination cell", _
                  Title:="Select Destination", _
                  Default:="A1", Type:=8) ' have user select "destination" cell
    On Error GoTo 0
    If rngDest Is Nothing Then
        wbSrc.Close
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' build dictionary from destination header row
    Dim cell As Range, c As Long
    For c = 1 To rngDest.Columns.Count
        key = Trim(rngDest.Cells(1, c))
        If Len(key) > 0 Then
            If dict.exists(key) Then
                MsgBox key & " duplicate column heading, ignoring", vbCritical
            Else
                dict.Add key, c
            End If
        End If
    Next
   
    ' scan source headers matching to destination column using dict
    Dim col As Range
    For c = 1 To UBound(arHeader, 2)
        key = Trim(arHeader(1, c))
        If dict.exists(key) Then
            'Debug.Print c, key, dict(key)
            rngDest.Cells(2, dict(key)).Resize(UBound(arData)).Value = Application.Index(arData, , c)
        Else
            'Debug.Print c, key, "no match"
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox rngSrc.Address & " copied to " & rngDest.Address, vbInformation
  
End Sub
```